# How to make the highchart fully occupied with the div that had set?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

currently i doing highCharts using coldfusion. I need to display 3 charts in table with same column size and the charts have to occupied the div that had set. I managed to display all the charts but the column size are not the same and the chart doesn't occupied the column. Below is the print screen of my image and code.
[image]

```js
<cfscript>
 categories=   ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'] ;

series=  [{
            'type': 'column',
            'name': 'Last Month',
            'data': ['80','136','220','314','371','424','522','611','679','730','806','876','906','1003','1044','1084','1120','1147','1228','1248','1259','1277','1278','1306','1318','1365','1413','1513','1522','1614']
        }, {
            'type': 'column',
            'name': 'MTD',
            'data': ['70','97','158','207','216','254','264','266','340','406','442','532','626','683','688','771','827','881','900','934','995','1074','1081','1091','1174','1236','1244','1316','1409','1486'    ]
        }, {
            'type': 'spline',
            'name': 'Target',
            'data': ['84','148','162','200','212','282','341','358','452','539','632','661','687','784','793','822','876','937','975','1035','1106','1159','1212','1239','1294','1298','1305','1340','1401','1479'],
            'marker': {
                'enabled': false
            }
        }];
</cfscript>

<cfscript>
  categories1= ['Overall','Appt Booking', 'Reception', 'Service Advisor', 'Completion Delivery Process'] ;

 series1 = [{
            'name': 'Last Month',
            'data': [3.775,3.5, 3.9, 4, 3.7],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }, {
            'name': 'MTD',
            'data': [ 3.775, 3.7, 3.5, 3.9, 4],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }, {
            'name': 'Target',
            'data': [3.725, 3.8,3.5, 3.7, 3.9],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }];
</cfscript>

<cfscript>
 categories2=   ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'] ;

series2=  [{
            'type': 'spline',
            'name':'WIP Cases',
            'data': [5,13,13,12,13,10,9,7,6,14,12,9,7,11,11,5,12,11,8,6,15,12,11,11,5,5,14,11,12,15,9],
            'marker': {
                'enabled': false
            }
        }];
</cfscript>

<cfscript>
 categories3=   ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'] ;

series3=  [{
            'type': 'spline',
            'name':'WIP Cases',
            'data': [5,13,13,12,13,10,9,7,6,14,12,9,7,11,11,5,12,11,8,6,15,12,11,11,5,5,14,11,12,15,9],
            'marker': {
                'enabled': false
            }
        }];
</cfscript>

$(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Combination chart',
            x: -1000
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
            },
            categories:<cfoutput>#serializeJson(categories)#</cfoutput>,
            tickInterval:29       },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },

            tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
        },

         legend: {
              itemStyle: {
              },

        },
        
        series:<cfoutput>#serializeJson(series)#</cfoutput>
    });
});
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    
    var categoryLinks = {
        'Overall': 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/Spiderweb.cfm?id=1234',
        'Appt Booking': 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/line.cfm',
        'Service Advisor': 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/combine.cfm'
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'container1'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -1000
        },

        pane: {
            size: '100%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: <cfoutput>#serializeJson(categories1)#</cfoutput>,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
             labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<a href="' + categoryLinks[this.value] + '">' +
                        this.value + '</a>';
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '8px',
                }
            }

        },

        yAxis: [{
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 3,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickPositions: [3,3.5, 4, 4.5, 5],
        }],

          plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

  legend: {
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: -100,
            x :-100,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },  

        exporting: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
        },
        series: <cfoutput>#serializeJson(series1)#</cfoutput>

    });
});
</script> 



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'container3'
        },

  title: {
           text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -1000

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'WIP Aging',
            },
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickPositions: [4, 6, 8, 10,12,14,16],
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            },
            categories:<cfoutput>#serializeJson(categories2)#</cfoutput>,
            tickInterval:30      },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
             

            tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
        },

        exporting: { enabled: false },

        legend: {
              itemStyle: {
                 fontSize:'5px'
              },

        },
        
        series:<cfoutput>#serializeJson(series2)#</cfoutput>
    });
});
</script>

</script> 



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'container4'
        },

  title: {
           text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -1000

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'WIP Aging',
            },
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickPositions: [4, 6, 8, 10,12,14,16],
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            },
            categories:<cfoutput>#serializeJson(categories3)#</cfoutput>,
            tickInterval:30      },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
             

            tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
        },

        exporting: { enabled: false },

        legend: {
              itemStyle: {
                 fontSize:'5px'
              },

        },
        
        series:<cfoutput>#serializeJson(series3)#</cfoutput>
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<body>
 <table  style="width:100%; pading:0 100px 0 100px;">
   <tr style="    font: bold 11px/16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center;background-color:#D5D9D8; color:white; line-height: 34px;text-shadow: #8F8E86 2px 2px 3px;">
     <td>Throughput</td>
     <td>CSI Score</td>  
     <td>WIP Cases</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="text-align:center;">
     <td><div id="container" style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
     <td><div id="container1" style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px; height: 300px; margin: 0 0 0 100px"></div></td>  
     <td><div id="container3" style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="text-align:center;">
     <td  style="text-align:center;background-color:#bebebe; color:white; font-size: 16px;height: 40px;">Utilization</td>
     <td  rowspan = 3>
      <div style="text-align:left">Bottom 20 overall</div>
      <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
       <td>Jill</td>
       <td>Smith</td> 
       <td>50</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Eve</td>
       <td>Jackson</td> 
       <td>94</td>
     </tr>
   </table><br><br><br><br><br>

   <div style="text-align:left">Bottom 20 for SA</div>
   <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
       <td>Jill</td>
       <td>Smith</td> 
       <td>50</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Eve</td>
       <td>Jackson</td> 
       <td>94</td>
     </tr>
   </table>

  </td>  
     <td>80</td>
   </tr>
    <tr style="text-align:center">
     <td rowspan = 2><div id="container4" style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 250px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
     <td>Doe</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="text-align:center">
     <td>John</td>
   </tr>
 </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Highcharts typically inherits the width from the containing div, I'm not sure if it does the same for the min/max-width though.

Comment: Why is this tagged with ColdFusion? This issue has nothing to do with ColdFusion.

Comment: cause i do the highcharts in coldfusion

Answer (score 3):

There is [a related reported issue on Highcharts' github with a workaround](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1157) that seems to be working in your case.

Solution is to add in CSS:

`.highcharts-container, .highcharts-container svg { width: 100% !important; }`

and additional setting for Firefox:

`table { table-layout: fixed; }`

Example with fix applied: http://jsfiddle.net/noz6xp99/

Comment: Hello, this doesn't work on my code. There are still have white space beside the charts

Comment: @chyman-91 Could you recreate your issue on a live example? You could change my demo - link in answer. Maybe you have some other CSS settings that are not allowing the fix to work? Maybe your min-width CSS setting is causing the problem? It is also possible to use [setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize) to force chart to have certain width and height.